# SaltStack if condition failed mapping values while running command

Tags: linux, saltstack, jinja

I'm trying to echo a line into sudoers file like so but I can't figure out the correct syntax it's wanting for that specific command.

```
gwconfig:
  cmd.run:
    {% if grains['ip4_gw'] == '192.168.1.1' %}
    - name: echo "%account_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
    {% elif grains['ip4_gw'] == '192.168.1.2' %}
    - name: echo "not working" >> /tmp/gwtest.txt
    {% endif %}
```

This fails with

> Rendering SLS 'base:linux.oshardening' failed: mapping values are not
> allowed here; line 12

I can run this command manually and it works fine.

If I replace the sudoers line with something else like this then is also works fine:

```
gwconfig:
  cmd.run:
    {% if grains['ip4_gw'] == '192.168.1.1' %}
    - name: echo "working" >> /tmp/gwtest.txt
    {% elif grains['ip4_gw'] == '192.168.1.2' %}
    - name: echo "not working" >> /tmp/gwtest.txt
    {% endif %}


vmname:
    ----------
    gwconfig:
        ----------
        __env__:
            base
        __sls__:
            linux.test
        cmd:
            |_
              ----------
              name:
                  echo "working" >> /tmp/gwtest.txt
            - run
            |_
              ----------
              order:
                  10000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running it as a multi-line value seems to work:

```
gwconfig:
  cmd.run:
    {% if grains['ip4_gw'] == '192.168.1.1' %}
    - name: |
        echo "%account_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
    {% elif grains['ip4_gw'] == '192.168.1.2' %}
    - name: echo "not working" >> /tmp/gwtest.txt
    {% endif %}
```